# Personal calendar for each user

Tags: 2013, calendar

I have added a calendar in my publishing site. Problem is this is a shared calendar which means all users can view each other's events that they have added.

How can I add a personal calendar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A calendar is essentially just a SharePoint list so you can manage permissions on it in just the same way you manage any other list.

Go to List Settings -> Advanced Settings.  The second section down is entitled Item-Level Permissions and allows you to restrict both read and edit to the user who created the item.

The comment from ErinsMatthew is correct - though in this case, unless you have 50,000 users you are unlikely to have issues.  From experience, calendars also tend to have a limited number of entries so I would be surprised if you hit performance issues.

Note that any users with Manage Lists permissions will see all items in the calendar, so if you want to use a common view then I would recommend you use a filter such as Created By = [Me].

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a shared calendar, you will have to live with this as a side effect unless you want to establish item-level permissions on each calendar entry. I would NOT recommend this due to the potential performance impact of [fine-grained permissions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg128955.aspx).

My recommended solution would be to implement [My Sites on your SharePoint server](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee624362.aspx).  This will allow every person with a login to SharePoint to have their own site, which can host a calendar, document library, or whatever.  If you need a consolidated rollup, you can use workflow to copy the items to a global calendar, or even create a view using a Data View Web Part (though that's more of a SharePoint 2010 way of doing it).

You could add a new calendar for each user if you only have a handfull to deal with, but this can become unmanageable over time.